# I have a old version jar,now I want to use jlink to generate a smaller jre,how to do it?

Tags: java, java-9, jlink

I have a java application used java8 and maven,now I want to use jdk9 to generate a smaller jre to package with my application,how to do it?
If it is impossible,could you give me a maven used jlink to generate small jre demo?My English is not so well,sorry and thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [use JDeps to analyze your dependencies on modules](https://blog.codefx.org/tools/jdeps-tutorial-analyze-java-project-dependencies/):

```
jdeps -summary -recursive --class-path $libs $jar
```

Replace `$libs` with all your dependencies (even transitive ones; [Maven can copy them](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html)) and $jar with your application JAR. The output then contains a list of dependencies on modules (look for `... -> java.*` and `... -> jdk.*`).

If you're on Linux, you can use this pipeline to get a sorted list of module names:

```
jdeps -summary -recursive --class-path 'jars/*' jars/app.jar
    | grep '\-> java.\|\-> jdk.'
    | sed 's/^.*-> //'
    | sort -u
```

If you're on Java 10 or later, you can use `--print-module-deps` instead of `-summary`.

Take that list and feed it into `jlink`:

```
jlink
    --module-path $jdk/jmods
    --add-modules $modules
    --output minimal-jre
```

If you also want to bind all platform services, throw in a `--bind-services`.

The following line will then list all the modules you determined plus their dependencies and maybe the services they bind:

```
minimal-jre/bin/java --list-modules
```

Comment: I think it is better to use `--print-module-deps` instead of `-summary`

Comment: Thanks, added that.

Comment: on 17, summary works fine. print-module-deps throws exception